# How can I straighten a 2' long wooden stick

Tags: bending

I am trying to make a bunch of Escrima Sticks (for Filipino Martial Arts), but I can't find enough straight wood. What should I do? I don't want to spend money.

Comment: Look up steam bending. Basically, steaming the wood long enough softens it s it can be bent; if you hold it in pisition while it cools and dries ou it will hold the new shape. How long this takes and how much bending you can do depends on the wood and how thick it is.

Comment: How bent is the wood you have and what type? Steam bending branches is not usually effective. Besides bending you can remove wood to leave the remaining wood straight such as by fashioning a makeshift drawknife or using a hatchet.

Answer (score 1):

Soak the sticks in water. This will make them pliable. Then put them in a brace or frame that holds them straight while they dry.